# jQuery get attribute of an html element

Tags: jquery

I have

```
$(elements[current]).html();
```

that returns

```
<a href="#"><img style="width:991px;height:230px;" src="img/image.jpg" alt="img"></a>
```

and i need to get the element a href value only. how can i do this?

Comment: do you mean like this http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Do spend some time on *references*

Comment: I don't think this question deserves negative vote. There are always people that have questions that others do know but others don't. That's the nature of the question. I am a newbie in jQuery, i am now scared to ask questions here :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(elements[current]).find('a').attr('href')`

Comment: That won't work because $(elements[current]) **is** the a tag, so $(elements[current]).find('a') will not work.

Comment: @jpic judging from the `html()`, the `a` is a child node of `elements[current]`

Comment: You could also do `$("a", "elements[current]").attr('href')`. It does the same thing, without the need to use `.find` :)

Comment: @ShadowScripter Except not as you have quotes around `elements[current]` which will make it not work.

Comment: @AdamTerlson Whops, didn't see that it was an element, I was thinking it was a class or something. It is valid without the quotes though. :P

Answer (score 3):

I assume `elements[current]` refers to the element that is the parent of your `<a etc...><img /></a>` set of elements?

If so, then the answer should:

```
$(elements[current]).children('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.attr`.

```
$(elements[current]).attr('href')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method in jquery that allow you to get and set the attribute of the html element.

Example : `$("img").attr("alt");`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(elements[current]).find('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
elements[current].firstChild.href
```